# Update Parent Page when PXRedirectHelper Window Popup Closed

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to update the parent page of a popup created using

```
PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(targetGraph, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.Popup);
```

I have tried using a PXException (throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(target, false, "");) to refresh the parent page, but that prevents any updates saved on the popup window, even when used in the popup's Persisted function.

Is there any other way to update the page specifically when the user saves or close and saves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an action to open the popup, we got the OnClosingPopup property of PXButton to "refresh" the parent page/graph. Here is an example pulled from our working code on the sales order to call a popup that updates the sales order and refreshes the sales order page when done with the popup.

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> OpenPopup;
[PXButton(OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Cancel, Tooltip = "Open the Popup")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Popup", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
public virtual void openPopup()
{
    PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(targetGraph, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.Popup);
}
```

While my example uses PXSpecialButtonType.Cancel, you might want to look into the other PXSpecialButtonType values which might better fit your example.

Comment: Thanks a ton Brendan! That worked. I did have OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Refresh, but that didn't work. The cancel one works perfectly. Is there any reason Cancel works but Refresh doesn't for this task?

Comment: not sure but I do recall having the same issue (refresh didn't work but cancel did for a "refresh").